# Update table with multiple fields from another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, concatenation

I am trying to update a field in a table in Postgres called `certificate_name` by concatenating 3 fields from another table (`first_name`, `middle_name`, and `last_name`).  I have tried several statements, but they all throw errors; my most recent attempt was the following:

```
update candidate_attributes ca
inner join "user" u on u.id=ca.candidate_user_id
set ca.certificate_name = concat(u.first_name, u.middle_name, u.last_name);
```

I'm getting an error that says:

> syntax error at or near "inner"....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's a syntax error... look up the `update` syntax. You cannot use `inner join` here; you should `update user`.

Comment: Can each of the source columns be NULL? What should happen if no row is found in the source table?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't valid in Postgres. Resembles SQL Server syntax.

[Read the manual on `UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) and use instead:

```
UPDATE candidate_attributes ca
SET    certificate_name = concat_ws(' ', u.first_name,u.middle_name,u.last_name)
FROM   "user" u
WHERE  u.id = ca.candidate_user_id;
```

I also threw in [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) instead of `concat()`, assuming you want a space between each part of the name.